# Can I Collect Entropy From A Wifi Adapter?

Tags: go, random, cryptography, wifi, entropy

Recently I was generating a GPG key and was made to wait for more entropy to be collected for /dev/random. I've found a few cool daemons that feed /dev/random entropy via microphones, webcams, etc...

- https://www.vanheusden.com/aed/
- https://www.vanheusden.com/ved/

I thought it might be a fun exercise to code one myself with the idea I have in mind (If possible). I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically collect signal noise from a wifi adapter. This is lower level than packet sniffing so I'm not sure where to start. I'm coding on Linux and I'd ideally use Go or Nim/C interop (Preferably Golang).

Assuming it's possible, I'm also wondering if I'd be able to do it without disrupting regular usage of the wifi adapter.

Comment: Go programs should use the [crypto/rand package](https://godoc.org/crypto/rand) instead of reading /dev/random or /dev/urandom directly.

Comment: Right but that doesn't mean I shouldn't develop a way of adding more entropy to the system.

Comment: I am trying to help out by letting you know what the recommended practice is for getting cryptographically secure pseudorandom numbers. I am not making a comment about adding entropy to the system.

Comment: Also see [When Good Randomness Goes Bad: Virtual Machine
Reset Vulnerabilities and Hedging Deployed Cryptography](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~syilek/ndss2010.html). Its provided for VMs, but the technique can help with entropy depletion in other pools. Another technique I use is to sample sensor data from mobile devices. See, for example, [Android PRNG](https://github.com/noloader/Android-PRNG/).